# Field validation bootstrap rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I 'm working on rails web application
In which I used simple bootstrap field validation like

```
<%= f.text_field :userName, class: "username-txtbx userpro-warning warning", required: "required"%>
```

But when I click on "Register" button to submit form,
Validation error appears on top of navbar. (as seen in pic. provided)

[image]

I just want that to display this error on form field, which is currently beneath the navbar.
What I should do to achieve this 
(A friend of mine has told me to use custom validations instead.
But I 'm not sure how to achieve this)

My form code,

```
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= devise_error_messages! %>


        <div class="reg-wrapper">
          <div class="register-header">
              <a href="<%= new_session_path(resource_name)%>">Already a member?</a>
              Register an Account
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="reg-tab active">Account Details</div>
                <div class="reg-tab-detail-data">
                  <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="user-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Username</span> <sup>*</sup></div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <%= f.text_field :userName, class: "username-txtbx userpro-warning warning", required: "required"%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="user-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>E-mail Address</span> <sup>*</sup></div>
                          <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <%= f.email_field :email, class: "username-txtbx", required: "required"%>
                              <div class="margin_t">
                                <%= f.check_box :chkEmail %> MAKE THIS FIELD HIDDEN FROM PUBLIC
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="user-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Password</span> <sup>*</sup></div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                              <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                              <% end %><br />

                              <%= f.password_field :password, class: "username-txtbx", autocomplete: "off", required: "required" %>
                              <div class="margin_t15px">
                                Password Strength
``                              <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress", style="margin-bottom: 0px;"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt"><span>Confirm Password</span> <sup>*</sup></div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content">
                              <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "username-txtbx", autocomplete: "off", required: "required" %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="margin_t15px">
              <div class="reg-tab active">Account Details</div>
                <div class="reg-tab-detail-data">
                  <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Profile Display Name</span></div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <%= f.text_field :profileDisplayName, class: "username-txtbx"%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="user-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Profile Picture</span> <sup>*</sup></div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <img src="<%= image_path('web/user-img.jpg') %>" alt="" class="user-img" />
                                <div class="margin_t">Upload a profile picture</div>
                                <%= f.file_field :avatar, required: "required" %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Gender</span></div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'mail', :checked => true %>
                              <%= label :gender, 'mail' %>
                              <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'femail'  %>
                              <%= label :gender, 'femail' %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="user-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Country/Region</span> <sup>*</sup></div>
                           <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">

                             <%= f.country_select :country %>

                           </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="margin_t15px">
              <div class="reg-tab active">Social Profiles</div>
                <div class="reg-tab-detail-data">
                  <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="user-icon fb-"></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Facebook Page</span> </div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <%= f.text_field :facebookPage, class: "username-txtbx"%>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="username-contents ">
                      <div class="user-icon twitter-"></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Twitter</span> </div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <%= f.text_field :twitter, class: "username-txtbx"%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="username-contents ">
                      <div class="user-icon gp-"></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Google+</span> </div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <%= f.text_field :google, class: "username-txtbx"%>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="username-contents">
                      <div class="user-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></div>
                      <div class="clearfix">
                          <div class="username-txt hover-icon"><span>Website (URL)</span> </div>
                            <div class="txtbx-content hover-icon">
                              <%= f.text_field :website, class: "username-txtbx"%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="comp-txt">
              <input type="checkbox" /> To complete registration, you must read and agree to our terms and conditions.
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="submit" value="Register" class="reg-button active">
              <%= link_to "Log in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
            </div>
        </div>

      <% end %>
```

CSS

```
    .username-txtbx{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    padding:0px 10px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 4px #eee;
    color: #aaa ;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
    .username-txtbx:focus{background:#FFF;}
.txtbx-content{
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for your form?

Comment: And CSS code you used too;

Comment: yes sure
but has it any impact?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7
I shared my form code

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal Have you scrolled page to this position?

Comment: yes than it exactly at the position where I want to see it

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 but just  after submitting form it causes the problem as I described in my question

Comment: Does the invalid warning scroll when you scroll the page? Or does it always stay in the nav bar?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal you can this one [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) or google to find list;

Comment: Can you show the css for `username-txtbx userpro-warning warning`?

Comment: I added code for username-txtbx
but for "userpro-warning warning", I added  this in single field to just check something
It has noting to do with it

Comment: @itzmukeshy7
Link you provided doesn't sieem to help
I downloaded it but it has dozens of files
Don't know what to do with it